# Mount CIFS in bash script

Tags: bash, permissions, mount, cifs

I'm trying to mount a CIFS share in a Bash script but it keeps failing when I run the script. When I use the exact same command directly in the console the mount succeeds.

This is the command I'm running.

```
mount -v -t cifs //hostname/share/ /mnt/share -o domain=<MyDomain>,username=<MyUsername>,password=<MyPass>
```

I'm running the script as root.

The error messages vary depending on the parameters I supply, and include:

```
mount error(13): Permissions denied
mount error(22): Invalid argument
```

I've read in other posts that the problem could be related to the lack of a specified security parameter. When I run `mount` after I executed the command in the console I can see how the system created the CIFS share. The system used "ntlm"

Output of "mount":

```
//hostname/share/ on /mnt/share type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,cache=strict,username=<MyUsername>,domain=<MyDomain>,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=10.149.239.30,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,serverino,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,actimeo=1)
```

So I added the `sec` parameter:

```
mount -v -t cifs //hostname/share/ /mnt/share -o sec=ntlm,domain=<MyDomain>,username=<MyUsername>,password=<MyPass>
```

Again, this runs fine in console but not in a bash script. It throws `mount error(13): Permissions denied` again.

I'm out of ideas, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use **all** of the options `mount` uses when executed in the console? I'd try to just copy the whole list to the script.

Comment: @dessert, yea but then the "error(22): Invalid argument" messages start